# How do I calculate the total number of likes for all of a user's posts in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project and I'm trying to calculate the total number of likes for a user based on their posts (i.e if a user has post with 10 likes and another with 5, the total likes must display 15) . I've tried various approaches, but I haven't been able to get it working.

Here is my models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(...)
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    email = models.EmailField(...)
    bio = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="user_post")

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created_at"]
```

And here I am trying to display the total number of likes for all posts from a specific user inside this html file (user profile):

```
...
    <p>Total likes: {{ post.likes.all.count }} </p>
...
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def show_user(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return redirect('user_list')
    else:
        return render(request, 'show_user.html', {'user': user , 'posts' : posts, 'request_user': request.user})
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Initially, I attempted to use the `{{ post.likes.all.count }}` template tag to display the total number of likes for each post. However, this didn't work as it didn't return any value on the screen.
2. Next, I tried using the {% add %} template tag within a loop to iterate over all the posts and accumulate the likes count. However, this resulted in a TemplateSyntaxError.

I am not sure what the best way to solve this issue is. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to calculate and display the total number of likes for a user's from all posts in Django.

Comment: Please post the *view* and the parts relevant in the template you render.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it as the many-to-many relation is confusing me. This is because I am trying to find the total number of likes a specific user (the author) has  based on all his posts (which are liked by many users). IF anyone can elaborate on that, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have updated the post to contain the view @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: why not use your total_likes helper method that you have?

Comment: The total_like helper works, in another page I use the following  **Likes: {{ post.total_likes }}**  and this shows the total likes **for a specific post**. But I am trying to get the **total number of likes a specific user has on all his posts**. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: you have specvified a related name so you should be able to access via `user.user_post.all()` ... or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the total number of likes for an author with:

```
from django.db.models import Count


@login_required
def show_user(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(
        User.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('post__likes')), pk=user_id
    )
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    return render(
        request,
        'show_user.html',
        {'user': user, 'posts': posts, 'request_user': request.user},
    )
```

in the template you can then render the total likes of the user with:

```
{{ user.total_likes }}
```

You can also boost counting the number of likes *per post* with:

from django.db.models import Count

```
@login_required
def show_user(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(
        User.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('post__likes')), pk=user_id
    )
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(num_likes=Count('likes')).filter(author=user)
    return render(
        request,
        'show_user.html',
        {'user': user, 'posts': posts, 'request_user': request.user},
    )
```

In the template you can then render this with:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {{ post }} (likes: {{ post.num_likes }})
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly when I annotated 'user'  :) . Is it possible to explain what happened in order for it to work? I am a bit confused, but very interested to know! I am very new to working with models in Django.

Comment: @KarminMahmood: you can work with `.annotate(..)` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to add some extra attribute to the object(s) generated from a queryset. With aggregates like `Count`, it will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then a `GROUP BY`, so we `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the post and then the likes table, and then use that to count the total number of likes, and group again by the user id.

Comment: So from my understanding so far: `user = get_object_or_404( User.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('post__likes')), pk=user_id )`, I am getting a **user** , and im taking that **user** from a model, with an extra *annotated* field called **total_likes**. And that is an *aggregate* count function that counts `post__likes` ( but I am confused to what this means and how it relates to my models). And finally, we *filter* out the *annotated model* using the **user_id**. I am confused as to how the total likes is calculated. Is it possible to clarify how counting the total likes works here? Thanks.